# Where should I put my Xiaomi backup file in order for it to be visible to the restore system?

Tags: backup, restore, xiaomi

My phone is MIUI Global 12.0.8, Android version 10 (QP1A.190711.020). I did a BAK file of some apps which I created using the backup mechanism of my phone directly.

I access the backup and restore functions with
"About phone --> Back up and restore --> Mobile device ---> Back up / Restore.

I put it inside any backup folders I saw on my phone. But when I come to the "restore" function, it says "No backups here yet".

Where should I put the BAK file in order for that stuff to work?

Answer (score 2):

The folder is
Redmi Note 9\Internal shared storage\MIUI\backup\AllBackup

The important point that I was missing is that the whole backup folder, say "16062022_172724" which contains all the BAK files should be put there, otherwise this will not work.